# if/else on a returned hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, hash

I would like to perform a query on a returned hash but get undefined method <= on Hash. My query looks like this

```
<% if @fixture_date <= (Date.today + 7.days) %>
 Display fixtures whos date falls in this range
<% else %>
 no fixtures
<% end %>
```

I have form that returns fixtures grouped by date

```
 <%= form_tag controller: 'predictions', action: 'create', method: 'post' do %>
 <% @fixture_date.sort.each do |date, fixture| %>
 <h5><%= date_format(date) %></h5><br>
 <% fixture.each do |fixture|%>

<%= fixture.home_team %> vs <%= fixture.away_team %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][home_team]", fixture.home_team %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][away_team]", fixture.away_team %>
<%= text_field_tag "predictions[][home_score]" %>
<%= text_field_tag "predictions[][away_score]" %><br />

<%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][fixture_date]", fixture.fixture_date %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][fixture_id]", fixture.id %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][user_id]", current_user.id %>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit predictions" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Example of hash returned

```
2013-04-17"=>[#<Fixture id: 3, home_team: "Man City", away_team: "Wigan", fixture_date: "2013-04-17", kickoff_time: "19:45", created_at: "2013-04-14 14:09:06", updated_at: "2013-04-14 14:09:06", prediction_id: nil>, #<Fixture id: 4, home_team: "West Ham", away_team: "Man Utd", fixture_date: "2013-04-17", kickoff_time: "19:45", created_at: "2013-04-14 14:09:06", updated_at: "2013-04-14 14:09:06", prediction_id: nil>, #<Fixture id: 5, home_team: "Fulham", away_team: "Chelsea", fixture_date: "2013-04-17", kickoff_time: "20:00", created_at: "2013-04-14 14:09:06", updated_at: "2013-04-14 14:09:06", prediction_id: nil>],
```

Do i need to query the value of the key, if so how would i go about doing that? Im guessing that if i was getting an array returned then this would work? or am i misunderstanding this?

I then thought about doing this in the controller and got this far

```
@fixture_date.select{ |key, hash| hash["fixture_date"] <= (Date.today + 7.days) }
```

But again i seem to get an error, this time

```
Cant convert String into Integer
```

Thanks

edit

```
def new
 @prediction = Prediction.new
 @fixtures = Fixture.all
 @fixture_date = @fixtures.group_by {|fd| fd.fixture_date}
 @fixture_date.select{ |k, v| v['fixture_date'].to_date <= (Date.today + 7.days) }
 end
```

View

```
<%= form_tag controller: 'predictions', action: 'create', method: 'post' do %>
<% @fixture_date.sort.each do |date, fixture| %>
<h5><%= date_format(date) %></h5><br>

<% fixture.each do |fixture|%>

<%= fixture.home_team %> vs <%= fixture.away_team %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][home_team]", fixture.home_team %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][away_team]", fixture.away_team %>
<%= text_field_tag "predictions[][home_score]" %>
<%= text_field_tag "predictions[][away_score]" %><br />

<%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][fixture_date]", fixture.fixture_date %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][fixture_id]", fixture.id %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "predictions[][user_id]", current_user.id %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit predictions" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You got it right. please give us the line of this error, but most likely it can be fixed with `hash["fixture_date"] .to_date`

Comment: ah something simple then that i didn't think about, will try the .to_date method, thanks

Comment: @fotanus ok so i just tried the answer below aswell as adding to_date with my original code, but all of the fixtures are shown not the ones that fall in the condition i set. Can you see any reason why it would not work?

Comment: also tried it in the console but get can convert string into integer but the page itself renders in my view?

Answer (score 2):

Try Date.parse:

```
@fixture_date.select! { |key, hash| Date.parse(hash["fixture_date"]) <= (Date.today + 7.days) }
```

Comment: any difference between this and .to_date ? thanks for your answer

Comment: ok so i just tried your answer aswell as adding to_date with my original code, but all of the fixtures are shown not the ones that fall in the condition i set. Can you see any reason why it would not work?

Comment: also tried it in the console but get can convert string into integer but the page itself renders in my view?

Comment: The other change I made was to change `select` (which always returns __something__) to `any?` (which sees if any matches are found).  Did you make this change too?

Comment: yes i tried this aswell, ill add the full controller now, suspect something may be wrong in there

Comment: now that I see what you are trying to do, `select` was closer, but not quite right, what you want is `select!`.  As it is, you are selecting the right data and not assigning it to anything.  Add an exclamation mark, and you will modify the value of `@fixture_date`.

Comment: ah right, wow such a minor change for the right result, thanks for taking a second look :)

Comment: hmmm that did'nt work, maybe its my view causing the problem, ive added that aswell